# How do I see both Resharper's and Visual Studio's refactoring suggestions?

Tags: resharper

In Resharper for Visual Studio, often I want to use a refactoring suggestion and I'm not sure whether it is part of Resharper or VS.  Sometimes I have to push Ctrl+. to open Resharper's refactorings and then hit escape and then push Alt+Enter to open VS's wrench or light bulb.

Is there a way to combine these into one menu or otherwise see both, of course without losing the VS refactorings?

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper used to be able to merge VS actions into the Alt+Enter menu, but right now as of 2022.3 this functionality is broken (see [RSRP-486822](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-486822)).

I suggest you disable "Hide Visual Studio Quick Action icons in the left editor margin" setting in R# options. This was you will be able to see VS actions using Ctrl+., and R# actions using Alt+Enter.

Comment: Thanks, already did that.  Is there any way to show both at once?

Comment: As I said, R# used to be able to merge VS actions into the Alt+Enter menu, but currently this is broken. Please subscribe to the issue to get notified when it's fixed.